# Verificar se string contém 4 números e 2 letras

Tags: c#

Olá estou a fazer um trabalho da escola e preciso de ajuda com tratamento de exceções.

*O problema é basicamente este:*
Tenho uma textbox onde o utilizador vai inserir a matrícula do seu veículo e preciso que a textbox tenha obrigatoriamente **4 números e 2 letras** e se não tiver irei lançar uma exceção com uma mensagem a dizer que a matrícula não é válida.

A ordem da matrícula precisa ser uma destas:

```
AZ - 11 - 11

11 - AZ - 11

11 - 11 - AZ
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isto?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode criar uma função 'checarMatricula' que retorna se a matricula é valida ou não.

```
public bool checarMatricula(string matricula) {
        int l = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < matricula.Length; i++) {
            int number;
            if(int.TryParse(matricula[i].ToString(), out number)) {
                n++;
            } else {
                l++;    
            }
        }
        if ( l == 2 && n == 4)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Dessa forma quando quiser utilizar basta chamar a função dentro de uma condição ou variável. Não coloquei para limitar em 6 o numero de caracteres pois imagino que já tenha feito isso no código.